# Puppeteer scrape value generated in javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

How do I scrape a value that is generated within Javascript.

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and now I'm stuck.  I have the page login stuff working.

The page looks like this in a browser and I want to extract the SoC% value and nothing else.  In this example the value is 92.16%

[image]

This page will auto update every 10 minutes.

I can see the part of the JS that returns the value but I don't know how to scrape this value into a variable in my script.

```js
if ('battery_soc' in d.last) {
  content+="<td>"+d.last.battery_soc+"%</td>";
}
else {
   content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td>";
}
```

Here is the full html page if that helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="Description" content="Select.Live is web based SCADA for SP Pro inverters and its system" />
        <meta name="Author" content="Selctronic Australia Pty Ltd" />
        <title>Select.Live Portal | Selectronic Australia</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/zebra_datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/ad-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/zebra_datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/user_geolocation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var geocodeKey = "";
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="ad-header">
        <button type="button" class="side-toggle left hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="open">
            <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="header-logo left"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    
<div class="section">

  <div align="center" class="side-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/systems"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span><span class="hideit">Systems</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/myprofile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span class="hideit">My Profile</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span><span class="hideit">Logout</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".side-menu li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
  </script>


  <div class="main-content container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="map" style="height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- My Systems -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-12 main-content-padding">
        <div class="main-content-inner">
          <div class="main-content-header">
            <h3>My Systems</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="main-content-body">
            <table id="ownerSystems" class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>System Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>SoC</th>
                  <th class="hidden-xs">Production</th>
                  <th class="hidden-xs">Purchased</th>
                  <th class="hidden-xs">Consumption</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div align="right"> <a href="#" class="add_system btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add a System</a> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Other systems (have installer access to these) 0 -->
    <div id="otherSystems" class="row hidden" >
<div class="col col-md-12 main-content-padding">
        <div class="main-content-inner">
          <div class="main-content-header">
            <h3>Other Systems</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="main-content-body">
            <table id="installerSystems" class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>System Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>SoC</th>
                  <th class="hidden-xs">Production</th>
                  <th class="hidden-xs">Purchased</th>
                  <th class="hidden-xs">Consumption</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="overlay_content" style="overflow-y: auto;">
          <div class="overlay_header">
            <div class="right"> <a href="#" class="overlay_close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay_body">
            <h3>Add a new System to your profile</h3>
            <p>Connect your Select.Live Device to your SP PRO and set it up so that it is connected to the Internet.</p>
            <p>Please find the Device ID and Serial number on the LCD screen of your Select.Live Device as shown in the example,
            and copy those details into the form below.
            </p>
            <img src="images/LCD_claim_Selectronic.png">
            <form id="claim_form" style="clear:both;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="claim_code">Device ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="claim_code" class="form-control" name="devhash" placeholder="id">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="claim_serial">Serial</label>
                <input type="text" id="claim_serial" class="form-control" name="serialnum" placeholder="serial number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="claim_type">Access Required</label><br>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="claim_type" value="owner" checked> Owner</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="claim_type" value="installer"> Installer</label>
              </div>
              <button type="button" id="add_claim" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">Add System</button>
            </form>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div id="claim_failed"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDl070Qq1sR3HnNr3LegChHPV8c7WWjZM4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: -37.7621346, lng: 145.3132782 },
        gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false
    });
    var getData=function(installer) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'systems/list'+(installer ? '/installer' : '/owner'),
            type:'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success:function(data) {
                var tableID = data.installer ? 'installerSystems' : 'ownerSystems';
                // data=JSON.parse(data);
                if(data.systems.length) {
                    var content="";
                    var time_diff;
                    data.systems.forEach(function(d) {
                        content+="<tr onmouseover='zoom("+d.lat+","+d.lng+")' onmouseout='zoomout()'>";
                        content+="<td><a href='/dashboard/"+d.did+"'>"+d.name+"</a></td>";
                        content+="<td>";
                        var con_stat="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign color-green s-large' style='vertical-align:middle;'></span> ";
                        if (d.events) con_stat="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign color-yellow s-large' style='vertical-align:middle;'></span> ";
                        if (d.last) {
                            time_diff = d.delta_ts;
                            console.log("time_diff="+time_diff);
                            if(time_diff<60) {
                                con_stat+="<span>"+Math.round(time_diff)+" seconds ago</span>";
                            }
                            else if(time_diff<1200) {
                                con_stat+="<span>"+Math.round(time_diff/60)+" minutes ago</span>";
                            }
                            else if(time_diff<3600) {
                                con_stat="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign color-red s-large' style='vertical-align:middle;'></span> ";
                                con_stat+="<span>"+Math.round(time_diff/60)+" minutes ago</span>";
                            }
                            else if(time_diff<86400) {
                                con_stat="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign color-red s-large' style='vertical-align:middle;'></span> ";
                                con_stat+="<span>"+Math.round(time_diff/3600)+" hours ago</span>";
                            }
                            else {
                                con_stat="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign color-red s-large' style='vertical-align:middle;'></span> ";
                                con_stat+="<span>"+Math.round(time_diff/86400)+" days ago</span>";
                            }
                            content+=con_stat;
                            content+="</td>";
                            if ('battery_soc' in d.last) {
                                content+="<td>"+d.last.battery_soc+"%</td>";
                            }
                            else {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td>";
                            }
                            if ('solar_wh_total' in d.last) {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>"+d.last.solar_wh_total.toFixed()+" kWh</td>";
                            }
                            else {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td>";
                            }
                            if ('grid_in_wh_total' in d.last) {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>"+d.last.grid_in_wh_total.toFixed()+" kWh</td>";
                            }
                            else {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td>";
                            }
                            if ('load_wh_total' in d.last) {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>"+d.last.load_wh_total.toFixed()+" kWh</td>";
                            }
                            else {
                                content+="<td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            content += "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign color-red s-large' style='vertical-align:middle;'></span>";
                            content += "<span>No Measurements Recorded</span></td>";
                            content += "<td>&mdash;</td><td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td><td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td><td class='hidden-xs'>&mdash;</td>";
                        }
                        content+="</tr>";
                        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: d.lat, lng: d.lng}, map: map, title:d.name});
                    });
                    $('table#'+tableID+' tbody').html(content);
                    if (data.installer) $('div#otherSystems.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
                }
                else if (!data.installer) {
                    $('table#'+tableID+' tbody').html("<tr><td colspan='7'>You don't have any SP Pro Systems</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    var addSystem=function() {
        var serial = $('#claim_serial').val();
        var code = $('#claim_code').val();
        var access = $('input[name=claim_type]:checked').val();
        console.log('Attempting to claim with serial='+serial+', code='+code+', access='+access);
        $.ajax({
            url:'systems/claim',
            type:'post',
            data: { code: code, serial: serial, access: access },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        })
          .done(function(data) {
                  var is_installer = (data.access == 'installer') ? true : false;
                  $('.overlay').hide();
                  $('div#claim_failed').html('');
                  $('form#claim_form input').val('');
                  getData(is_installer);
                })
          .fail(function(data) {
                  if (data.responseJSON.reason.match(/No matching inverter/i)) {
                      $('div#claim_failed').html('<p>&nbsp;</p><h3 class="text-danger">Could not find a matching inverter</h3>'
                                                +'<p class="text-danger">Please check the following to fix this error:</p>'
                                                +'<ul class="text-danger" style="padding-left:20px;">'
                                                +'<li>Check that the Select.Live Device is powered on with text visible on the screen'
                                                +'<li>Check that the Select.Live Device screen shows "Cloud: OK" and an IP address'
                                                +'<li>If the Select.Live Device screen shows "Cloud: ERROR" or "Cloud: NO LAN":'
                                                +'<ul style="padding-left:50px;">'
                                                +'<li>for WiFi connection, check your WiFi router is operating correctly, and reset it if necessary'
                                                +'<li>for WiFi connection, check that there is a good WiFi signal at your Select.Live device<br>'
                                                +      '(use your mobile phone or tablet to confirm that the WiFi signal is present)'
                                                +'<li>for Ethernet connection, check that the cable is plugged in firmly at both ends;'
                                                +     ' also check using another device, e.g. a laptop computer, that the cable is working.'
                                                +'</ul></ul>'
                                                +'<p class="text-danger">If you have checked all the above and still get this error when you '
                                                +'attempt to add the system, you will need to reset your Select.Live device and start the '
                                                +'setup process again.  To reset your Select.Live Device, press and hold the black reset button '
                                                +'for 10 seconds.</p>');
                  }
                  else if (data.responseJSON.reason.match(/Access Denied/i)) {
                      $('div#claim_failed').html('<p>&nbsp;</p><h3 class="text-danger">Access denied by owner</h3>'
                                                +'<p class="text-danger">The owner of this SP PRO has not given permission for you to have access.</p>'
                                                +'<p class="text-danger">Please check you entered the correct <b>Device ID</b> and <b>Serial number</b>.'
                                                +' If you think they are correct, you will need to ask the owner of this SP PRO to grant access.</p>');
                  }
                  else if (data.responseJSON.reason.match(/No Owner/i)) {
                      $('div#claim_failed').html('<p>&nbsp;</p><h3 class="text-danger">Access Denied</h3>'
                                                +'<p class="text-danger">Installer access to this SP PRO is not allowed.</p>');
                  }
                  else {
                      $('.overlay').hide();
                      alert(data.responseJSON.reason);
                  }
                });
    };
    $('a.add_system').on('click',function(){
        $('.overlay').show();
    });
    $('a.overlay_close').on('click',function(){
        $('.overlay').hide();
    });
    $('#add_claim').on('click',addSystem);
    $('button.side-toggle').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("opened")) {
            $(this).removeClass("opened");
            $(".side-menu").removeClass("in");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("opened");
            $(".side-menu").addClass("in");
        }
    });
    var zoom=function(x,y) {
        map.panTo({lat:x,lng: y});
        map.setZoom(18);
    }
    var zoomout=function() {
        map.setZoom(10);
    }
    $(window).ready(function() {
        getData(false);
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
    });
</script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my script so far

```js
const scrapePersons = async () => {
    // import launchChrome and newPage from the browser.js file in the same directory
    const { launchChrome } = require("./browser");

    // Flow 1 => Launching chrome and opening a new tab/page
    const [newPage, exitChrome] = await launchChrome();
    const [page] = await newPage();

    const emailSelector="input[name=email]";
    const pwdSelector="input[name=pwd]";
    const btnSelector=".btn";

    // exit the function if the tab is not properly opened
    if (!page) return;

    // Flow 2 => Visiting a website's home page
    const url = "https://select.live/";
    console.log("Opening " + url);
    try {
        await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0", // wait till all network requests has been processed
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.error("Unable to visit " + url, e);
        await exitChrome(); // close chrome on error
        return; // exiting the function
    }

    //Perform the Login
    await page.waitForSelector(emailSelector);
    console.log('40 Found name="email" on page');

    await page.waitForSelector(pwdSelector);
    console.log('50 Found name="pwd" on page');

    await page.waitForSelector(btnSelector);
    console.log('55 Found the button with class namne btn');

    await page.type(emailSelector, 'Username Goes Here');
    await page.type(pwdSelector, 'Password Goes Here');
    console.log('60 Entered email and password');

    //Click the Login Butotn
    try{
        await page.click(btnSelector);
        console.log('70 Clicked the Login Button');
    }
    catch(e){
       console.error('Unable to click the login button' + btnSelector + ' ', e)
    }

    // Find the Power Percentage Value
    

    await exitChrome(); // close chrome
    console.log('900 Exited Chrome')
};

module.exports = scrapePersons;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try waiting for table cell to be rendered with [page.waitForSelector](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
// systems table row
const socSelector = '#ownerSystems tbody tr';

// wait for it to render
const socCell = await page.waitForSelector(socSelector, {
    visible: true
});

// extract value from third cell for each row
const socVal = await page.evaluate(socSelector => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`${socSelector} td:nth-child(3)`)).map(el => el.textContent), socSelector);

console.log(socVal);
```

Comment: WOW you got it in one.  Worked perfectly. I feel guilty that I didn't have to do anything.  I usually program in C# and even then not that well.  Lots of concepts in your answer that I don't understand.

Comment: How does that selector match the value to extract?  I see the ID OwnerSystems but that is in the table header. But I can't see how it matches the desired value from there.  If you are too busy to answer, no problem but thanks heaps for the solution.

Comment: @DavidP great. selector is the key here, if it doesn't work, then you might need to tweak it. there are already a few tables on the page, but they're empty, and they're populated later, by adding rows. so when the first row appears, the selector matches all rows in that table, and in each row the third cell

Comment: @DavidP you'll get a better feeling if you go to the page, open dev console,, and run `document.querySelectorAll('#ownerSystems tbody tr td:nth-child(3)')`. by modifying css selector you can also get other cell values if needed